# Keytool: What values may be used for the storetype

Tags: keytool

When using Java 11, what values can be used for the `storetype` parameter to `keytool`? The [online documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/keytool.html) gives some examples but does not say what all the valid values are.

Is there a way to have `keytool` list the suported store types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its directly transfered into the `KeyStore.getInstance(storetype)`-parameter ( as you can [see here](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/f4d80957e89a19a29bb9f9807d2a28351ed7f7df/src/share/classes/sun/security/tools/KeyTool.java#L763)).

Basically in JDK11 it is on oracle implementation from [the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#keystore-types)

- jceks
- jks
- dks
- pkcs11
- pkcs12

There are two more implemented in KeyTool runnin on a Windows-System: Windows-MY and Windows-ROOT.